# Set keep-alive in HttpClient in Spring xml

Tags: httpclient, keep-alive

We are using the apache HttpClient library to manage a pool of connections for some Java remoting.

Looking at the TCP traffic, it appears that the keep-alive flag is NOT being set, and our firewall is chopping off these connections.

Our spring config looks like this:

```
<bean name="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <property name="timeout" value="${pdcCreditCheck.maxTimeout}"/>
    <property name="httpConnectionManager" ref="remotingConnectionManger"/>
</bean>

<bean id="remotingConnectionManger"
      class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
    <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerHost" value="5"/>
</bean>
```

I was hoping that there might be some flag I could set here, which corresponds to the TCP keep-alive flag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the JVM flag *http.keepAlive*. For more info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.